# What sort of menu stucture/site design is appropriate when there are hundreds of pages to be described and referenced?

Tags: design

I'm creating a WordPress website/blog for the purpose of sharing years worth of technical works in physics, quantitative finance and mathematics. Most of these works are in the form of Mathematica notebooks or pdf/cdf representations of such notebooks. I plan to devote a WordPress "page" to each notebook and on this page I will describe the subject material, show a preview visualization or two, and then provide a link to the notebook file so readers can view it and perhaps download it.

The design problem is that there will be eventually be hundreds of such pages. Could members of this community offer suggestions, or provide pointers to example sites where this type of problem has been addressed?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Why Wordpress?  Wordpress is intended for blogs, where the primary organisation is the day the entry was made.  

How about doing it with a Wiki engine instead?  If you think about it, Wikipedia has hundreds of thousands of pages that are easily discoverable.  You have search, you can do any number of different index pages, and you can easily link between them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some complementary approaches:

1. Search: I'd probably go for an instant search that divides the contents into categories or groups while you search. Pages that really have an insane number of contents might even opt for only showing a search input in the Home ([FreeFullPDF](http://www.freefullpdf.com/) for example). This is obviously not necessary, but I would give the search a priority place, as it will probably one of the most used tools in your site (at least, it will be the fastest way to find information).
2. Categories menu: You probably have some sort of categorization. If it's not by subject, you can organize items by publication date or alphabetical order (so groups of letters). This first level or organization should probably be accessible from anywhere on the site, so a top menu for example might be the best option. This qould be the equivalent of a Browse. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com) or [Ebay](http://ebay.com) are good examples. You know what you are looking for? Use the search. You want to peek around? Use the categories.
3. Index: I think a good example of an index that is not that terrible to navigate through is [Nature](http://www.nature.com/siteindex/index.html)'s index. Apart from the list of items, you could have filter options as an internal menu. I'd suggest you don't add descriptions in the index (just a title), but use a tooltip instead. That way, information is available for those who want to go deeper, but the navigation is kept reasonably easy for those who don't. And in the tooltip you can add more info, like the year or the authors.